# Bitters error ("Undefined variable: $font-stack-system")

Tags: gulp, mixins, bourbon

My folder structure:

```
- app
-- sass
--- style.scss
--- base
--- bourbon
```

In my style.scss I import bourbon and base (and neat):

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "base/base"; // bitters
@import "neat/neat"; // bourbon grid
```

When I run "$gulp" (gulp is installed globally) I get the error:

```
[Error: app\sass\base\_variables.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$font-stack-system".
    on line 6 of app/sass/base/_variables.scss
>> $base-font-family: $font-stack-system;
   -------------------^
]
  formatted: 'Error: Undefined variable: "$font-stack-system".\n        on line 6 of app/sass/base/_variables.scss\n>> $base-font-family: $font-stack-system;\n   -------------------^\n',
```

(+ some more "Undefined variable" errors from "base" (bitters)) When I delete the line:

```
@import "base/base"; // bitters
```

It works. So I think there is a file missing but I don't know which.

EDIT: **I found the error** - the console always installs an old bourbon install (v. 4.x) and i need v. 5.x.

Comment: Good find, thank you. Additionally for any other readers happening to pop in here I had to do, gem install bourbon --pre. From there I added to my gemfile, gem 'bourbon', '5.0.0.beta.4'

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer even if it was you :)